# Assign values to a multidimensional array being member of a structure C++/Qt

Tags: arrays, qt, structure

I have a structure which includes a multidimensional array of QStrings *array2D*:

```
/* stat.h */
#include <QString>

struct stat
{
    QString name;
    QString array2D[2][4];
}
extern struct stat myStat;

/* stat.cpp */
#include <"stat.h">
struct stat myStat = { "Structure 1", { {"one","two","three","four"},{"five","six","seven","eight"} } };
```

This piece of code WORKS. However, the structure is going to get as new members more complex arrays of strings, of 3 and 5 dimensions, with dozens and hundreds of elements. Putting everything in the same line will look ugly, so I need to find a smarter way of initialization by using some reference to the array, not listing it all. I've tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
/* stat.cpp */
#include <"stat.h">

QString myArray[2][4] = { {"one","two","three","four"},{"five","six","seven","eight"} };
struct stat myStat = { "Structure 1", myArray}; // BAD!!
struct stat myStat = { "Structure 1", myArray[][]}; // BAD!!
struct stat myStat = { "Structure 1", &myArray}; // BAD!!
```

This didn't work either:

```
/* stat.cpp */
#include <"stat.h">

struct stat myStat = { "Structure 1",NULL};
myStat.array2D = { {"one","two","three","four"},{"five","six","seven","eight"} }; // BAD!!
```

What workaround can be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the same than when you try to copy the values from a table to another using a simple '=' opperator. You cannot.

```
int a[3] = {5,5,5};
int a2[3] = a;
```

> error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

You have two choices :
1) Use a pointer in your struct (instead of copiyng the values, you point to the array)

```
struct stat
{
    QString name;
    QString * array2D[2][4];
}
extern struct stat myStat;
```

or

```
struct stat
{
    QString name;
    QString * array2D[4];
}
extern struct stat myStat;
```

(depending of what you really want)

Then, you'll have to give the array manually...

2) do the copy yourself.

However, consider to learn C++ : You will find out that "struct" is optional when declaring a variable, and that a constructor fits your needs also.

Consider also using QVector/QStringList